# CSS rotate transform - left and top issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent div on which I am applying a rotation transform of -90 deg. Inside the div, one of the child should not transform, I tried transform:none and all its variants but nothing worked and it gets transformed anyways. So, I had to apply a reverse rotation on the child element to set it horizontal.

Now the problem which occurs is that changing the left of child on which reverse rotation was applied actually changes its top and changing top changes its left when altered using Firebug. So the child element is displayed at a wrong position.

```
if(self._sOrientation == "vertical"){
             self.RotatePH($thisComp.closest('.ComponentFrame'),"-90deg");
             if(self.isIE==false){
                self.RotatePH($thisComp.find('.revertTransform'),"90deg");
//                $thisComp.find('.revertTransform').css('-moz-transform', 'none');
             }
```

Actually the component is too complex  to provide any usable code on stack overflow

**Edit:**

I believe the second rotation should be about the axis of the main component instead of rotating about itself. Is it possible to change axis of rotation?

**The child has position:fixed; if that matters**

Comment: So..? unless you provide the code or a demo, what do you expect us to do about it..?!

Comment: for parent div you already choose `-90 deg` then for child `div` you can reverse it by giving `90deg`. this is just a small part of your question.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QFCmY/) to better understand your problem, and i think it's not something related to transformation axis.

More simply, when you alter top, or left position of the child element, it moves correctly referring to it's parent and then the transformation take place.

[image: First image]

#### *The child div alter it's position refering to parent div and inheriting it's transformations.*

So the final effect that you see is that the object is altering it's left position when you tweak the top and viceversa, but in fact it's not.

[image: Second Image]

#### *Child div seems to moved top and left, but in fact it's not.*

I suggest you to change your approach if it's applicable in your situation, and create a fake_parent element that is a child instead (you can see that in the fiddle).

```
//INSTEAD OF THIS APPROACH

<div class="parent">PARENT DIV
        <div class="child">CHILD DIV</div>
</div>    

//USE THIS APPROACH
<div class="fake_child">CHILD DIV
        <div class="fake_parent">PARENT DIV</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    width:100px;
    margin:3em;
    padding:2em;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    background-color:rgb(0, 112, 255);
}

.child {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    padding:1em;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

.fake_child{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 3em;
    position: relative;
}

.fake_parent{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:200%;
    background-color: rgb(0,121,255);
    top:0;
    left: 0;
       transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    z-index: -1;

}

body {
    background-color: #ccc;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer but I can't use this approach. The child has position:fixed; if that matters

Comment: To use this approach you should set position fixed to a dummy container, and leave the fake_child with relative positioning

Answer (score 0):

can't you use transform-origin (http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/):

```
-webkit-transform-origin: center center;
-moz-transform-origin: center center;
-o-transform-origin: center center;
transform-origin: center center;
```

Comment: I have been trying the same since yesterday but can't find the value for the origin to make it work.

Comment: I think the parent should have the the transform-origin set to center center as well

Answer (score 0):

> I believe the second rotation should be about the axis of the main component instead of rotating about itself. Is it possible to change axis of rotation?

Yes, if you know the width of the parent (or the ratio of the child's width to the parent's width, I believe). You can use `transform-origin` to have the child rotate back to its original position by setting `transform-origin: hpw hpw`, where `hpw` is half the width of the parent.

If we only rotated the parent and the child was at (0,0) relative to the parent, the child would end up in the bottom left corner of the parent. Imagine a box with its width and height both set to the width of the parent, and positioned at (0,0) relative to the rotated parent. (It follows that the child is in the bottom left corner of this box.) It should be clear that rotating this box will put the child back to it's original position and rotation.

The top and left of the child will still be relative to the rotated parent, so you'll have to position the child with `left: your_top * -1` and `top: your_left`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HTCwL/1/

**Edit**: Here's an animated version of the demo to make things clearer http://jsfiddle.net/HTCwL/2/

Relevant CSS:

```
#parent {
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px; left: 150px;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: -10px;
    top: 150px;
    border: 1px solid red;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 75px 75px;
}
```

**Edit**: Yes, the child having position fixed matters. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform,

> If the property has a value different than none [...] the object will act as a containing block for position: fixed elements that it contains.

The containing block for fixed elements is normally the html element (see http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Containing_blocks) but when the parent of a fixed element has a transform set it becomes their containing block. I'm not aware of any way to avoid that.